# How to move files to a new folder or subfolders based on parts of the file name?

Tags: batch-file

I have a folder where lots of .tif files drop into.

They all start with `MW_` or `SW_` and later also `NSSW`. So I need to be able to expand from the first two later to `NSSW`.

I have a batch file already that first moves the files into the folder `MW` or `SW` based on the first 2 characters of the file name. Here is my current batch file and it works just fine. But I think I need a second batch file or addition to this to do the below 1 & 2 steps. Please see below, after this code.

```
REM Sort by First name.
REM This script creates a folder for either the full file name,
REM or if it contains an underscore, the part before the underscore.

REM TODO - Don't copy over existing files.
REM TODO - Move files into Sub folders based on Date in file name "last 8 characters .tif

@echo off
REM Needed because you are working with variables that are immediately called
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

REM Start of the loop to get all files with a psd or jpg Extension
for %%A in (*.tif *.jpg *.pdf) do (
   echo file found  %%A

   REM Grabs only the file name
   for /f "delims=" %%B in ("%%A") do set fname=%%~nB
   REM Grabs only the extension
   for /f "delims=" %%C in ("%%A") do set fextn=%%~xC

   REM Using the File name it separates it into 2 part using "_" as a delimiter so 120_low becomes 120 and low
   for /f "tokens=1* delims=_" %%D in ("!fname!") do set folname=%%D
   echo folder name !folname!

   REM Checks for the existence of the folder, if the folder does not exist it creates the folder
   if not exist "!folname!" (
      echo Folder !folname! does not exist, creating
      md "!folname!"
   ) else (
      echo Folder !folname! exists
   )

   REM Moves the file to the folder
   echo Moving file %%A to folder !folname!
   REM   if not exist "%%D\%%A" move "%%A" "!folname!"
   if not exist "%%D\%%A" copy "%%A" "!folname!"

   REM  add the date DDMMYYYY to the end of each file. Name can be 80 characters long.
   rem ren "!folname!\%%A" "????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????_%date:~-10,2%%date:~-7,2%%date:~-4,4%.tif"
)

echo Finished
pause
```

So here is what I need I guess. A second or 3rd batch file to do the below. I hope, someone can help.

**Note:** Please keep in mind that if a file exists it renames the copy when moving with `xxxx(1).tif`, `xxx(2).tif`, etc. on the end of file name.

1. Move files now listed in `MW` folder into new or existing subfolders based on the name of the file from the 4th to 10th character of the file name or from the 4th character to the second or next "_".
2. Move file in subfolder of the named folder to a sub date named folder based on last 8 characters of file name.

What I need is to then move the files from the `MW` folder into new or existing subfolders based on the last 7 characters of the file name "the date section".

For example we start with `MW` files
Files coming in to folder `C:\temp\Test_Moving_Files\`

```
MW_VRL5VF10000_6542234_01052016.TIF 
MW_Flybuys_677888_01052016.TIF 
MW_VRL5VF10000_333443_02052016.TIF
MW_Flybuys_555555_02052016.TIF
MW_goodguys_534535_02052016.TIF
MW_goodguys_222222_02052016.TIF
MW_Flybuys_123443_03052016.TIF
MW_Flybuys_3545555_03052016.TIF
MW_goodguys_444444_03052016.TIF
MW_goodguys_888888_03052016.TIF
```

Output to subfolders should be sorted to subfolders like below:

```
MW\VRL5VF10000\01052016\MW_VRL5VF10000_6542234_01052016.TIF
MW\VRL5VF10000\02052016\MW_VRL5VF10000_333443_02052016.TIF

MW\Flybuys\01052016\MW_Flybuys_677888_01052016.TIF
MW\Flybuys\02052016\MW_Flybuys_555555_02052016.TIF
MW\Flybuys\03052016\MW_Flybuys_123443_03052016.TIF
MW\Flybuys\03052016\MW_Flybuys_3545555_03052016.TIF

MW\goodguys\01052016\MW_goodguys_222222_02052016.TIF
MW\goodguys\02052016\MW_goodguys_534535_02052016.TIF
MW\goodguys\03052016\MW_goodguys_444444_03052016.TIF
MW\goodguys\03052016\MW_goodguys_888888_03052016.TIF
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks the task can be achieved by modifying

```
   REM Using the File name it separates it into 2 part using "_" as a delimiter so 120_low becomes 120 and low
   for /f "tokens=1* delims=_" %%D in ("!fname!") do set folname=%%D
   echo folder name !folname!

   REM Checks for the existence of the folder, if the folder does not exist it creates the folder
   if not exist "!folname!" (
      echo Folder !folname! does not exist, creating
      md "!folname!"
   ) else (
      echo Folder !folname! exists
   )
```

to

```
   REM Using the file name it separates it into 4 parts using "_" as a delimiter.
   for /f "tokens=1-4 delims=_" %%D in ("!fname!") do set "folname=%%D\%%E\%%G"
   echo Folder name !folname!

   REM Checks for the existence of the folder path. If the folder
   REM path does not exist, it creates the complete folder structure.
   if not exist "!folname!\*" (
      echo Folder !folname! does not exist, creating ...
      md "!folname!"
   ) else (
      echo Folder !folname! exists.
   )
```

Instead of using just first substring of underscore delimited file name, the code above uses now first, second and fourth substring. I did not test it!

Command **MD** can create also multiple folders at once and therefore variable `folname` can be also a folder path string. Well, I suggest to rename the variable `folname` in your batch code for example to `FolderPath`.

Of course you must use `folname` or better `FolderPath` also in rest of batch script instead of `%%D`.